# "Undefined control sequence" in option of own package, but not within the document

Tags: package-writing, package-options, undefined

It's my first question, sorry if there are any mistakes!

I'm trying to create a package with the clsguide. In the package, I define an own command and I want to use this to set an option (storing a variable with the content of the command).

An example for the package:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{example}

\DeclareKeys{
   owncommand.code = \newcommand{\owncmd}{Use this text.}
}

\DeclareKeys{
   expression.store = \@expression
   expression.usage = load
}

\ProcessKeyOptions
\endinput
```

An example for the document:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[owncommand, expression = \owncmd]{example}

\begin{document}
   Test.
\end{document}
```

But I get the error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \owncmd
```

Using \owncmd within the document causes no error. So actually, \owncmd is not undefined. Where I do the mistake?

EDIT: Since I was asked for the use case. It is a package for personal use. I want to create worksheets with the current learning unit in the header like this:

[image: learning unit in the header]

I often have to use such "special" symbols. That's why I just define a command to get the right symbol. So I modify the package:

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.sty}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\RequirePackage{babel}
\RequirePackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\DeclareKeys[serdar]{
    fancysymbol.code = {
        \newfontfamily\arabicfont{Microsoft Uighur}
        \newcommand{\fancysymb}{
            \foreignlanguage{arabic}{\LARGE\arabicfont ﷺ}
        }
    },
    worksheettopic.store = \@worksheettopic,
    worksheetlayout.code = {\chead{\@worksheettopic}}
}

\ProcessKeyOptions[serdar]
\endinput
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[
   fancysymbol, 
   worksheettopic = {The Prophet \fancysymb}, 
   worksheetlayout
]{\jobname}

\begin{document}
   Test.
\end{document}
```

If I understand your solutions correctly,they will work only for the option `worksheettopic = fancysymb` and not for the "combined" one with `worksheettopic = The Prophet fancysymb`.

Of course, it's possible to move `\chead` in the preamble after loading the package. But I am searching for a solution within the package. Is there a (simple) possibilty?

Comment: the option list is also processed for classic option handling, and this requires all the option values to be defined before the package is called.

Comment: So, is there no way to modify the package  to get the document example working?

Comment: er, basically no, I think. It dies before the package file is seen.

Comment: the desired syntax seems rather strange, the user of the package would need to know that the package defines `\owncmd` to use it in the other option. what is the use case here?

Comment: I edit my question where you find the use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that modern LaTeX has two parallel mechanisms for package option. The first uses the entire option list inside of an `\edef`-expression, so your input has to be safe against an `\edef` (hence fails if you input `\owncmd`, as it's not defined when you hand in the options), and another mechanism that forwards the keys "as is" to the underlying package. As a result, your options have to be protected against expansion, but at the same time your protection mechanism must not interfere with the list in an unexpanded form if your key=value solution uses the new "as is" method.

The built in `\ProcessKeyOptions` uses the "as is" list. So you can't just use `\protect` to not expand your `\owncmd` without that `\protect` showing up in the result of your keys. For this reason, the following suggests using `expkv-opt`. `expkv-opt` uses the "as is" list as well, but supports expansion-expressions at use-time. With this it is possible to protect your `\owncmd` without the used protection mechanism actually showing up in the value.

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.sty}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\RequirePackage{expkv-def,expkv-opt}
\ekvdefinekeys{serdar}
  {
     protected code owncommand = \newcommand\owncmd{Use this text.}
    ,store expression = \serdarexpression
  }
\ekvoProcessLocalOptions{serdar}
\endinput
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
% any of the following lines work
% using the result of \csname owncmd\endcsname as value for expression
\usepackage[owncommand, c: expression = owncmd]{\jobname}
% expanding \unexpanded{\owncmd} once (resulting in \owncmd)
%\usepackage[owncommand, o: expression = \unexpanded{\owncmd}]{\jobname}
% gobbling \protect leaving just \owncmd
%\usepackage[owncommand, g: expression = \protect\owncmd]{\jobname}

\begin{document}
Test.
\serdarexpression   
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Variant with your extended MWE (no typeset result, I don't have the font, and I didn't want to spend time searching for one containing your glyph):

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.sty}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\RequirePackage{babel}
\RequirePackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\RequirePackage{expkv-def, expkv-opt}

\ekvdefinekeys{serdar}
  {
     protected noval fancysymbol =
      \newfontfamily\arabicfont{Microsoft Uighur}%
      \newcommand{\fancysymb}{\foreignlanguage{arabic}{\LARGE\arabicfont ﷺ}}
    ,store worksheettopic = \@worksheettopic
    ,protected noval worksheetlayout = \chead{\@worksheettopic}
  }
\ekvoProcessLocalOptions{serdar}

\endinput
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[
   fancysymbol, 
   o: worksheettopic = \unexpanded{The Prophet \fancysymb}, 
   worksheetlayout
]{\jobname}

\begin{document}
   Test.
\end{document}
```

---

There is a very simple solution to your problem: Don't use package options for these settings, but instead set up your package in a way that it provides a "setup" macro that does the option handling after the package was loaded. For instance:

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.sty}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\RequirePackage{babel}
\RequirePackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\RequirePackage{expkv-def, expkv-opt}

\ekvsetdef\serdarsetup{serdar}
\ekvdefinekeys{serdar}
  {
     protected noval fancysymbol =
      \newfontfamily\arabicfont{Microsoft Uighur}%
      \newcommand{\fancysymb}{\foreignlanguage{arabic}{\LARGE\arabicfont ﷺ}}
    ,store worksheettopic = \@worksheettopic
    ,protected noval worksheetlayout = \chead{\@worksheettopic}
  }

\endinput
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{\jobname}
\serdarsetup{
   fancysymbol, 
   worksheettopic = The Prophet \fancysymb, 
   worksheetlayout
 }

\begin{document}
   Test.
\end{document}
```

This circumvents the issue of processed option lists altogether.

Comment: Thank you. I will need more time to understand the code :D. Does this also work for `expression = foo \owncmd`?
I editted my question with more details, fyi.

Comment: @SerdarUludağ for `expression = foo \owncmd` you can't use the `c:` and `g:` variants, but `o: expression = \unexpanded{foo \owncmd}` should work fine.

Comment: Thank you for this solution. Actually, it is exactly what I want. But the "problem" is that the option `o: worksheettopic = \unexpanded{The Prophet \fancysymb}` is less convenient in contrast to use `\chead{The Prophet \fancysymb}` in the document. Sorry for having so special wishes 

Comment: @SerdarUludağ see my edit for an easy solution that works, but beware, it doesn't use package options anymore...

Comment: That is THE solution! There are some other package options I already declared. If I understand it correctly, the transfer from `\DeclareKeys` to `\ekvdefinekeys{serdar}` shouldn't be too difficult. :)

Comment: @SerdarUludağ you don't have to transform your keys, though I prefer my own package for key=value stuff (I'm the author of `expkv`) you can do the same with `\DeclareKeys`, there you'd use `\SetKeys[serdar]` instead of `\ekvset` or `\ekvsetdef`. So if you don't want to switch to `expkv` (no hard feelings) you can just use `\newcommand\serdarsetup{\SetKeys[serdar]}` and stick to your `\DeclareKeys` defined keys. Just pay attention which keys need `.usage = load` and which don't.

Comment: The only real argument in your question to change to `expkv` would've been the expansion expressions, if you don't need them you can use whichever package you'd like that implements key=value (though I'd only advice you to either use the LaTeX internal key=value parser, or `expkv`, or if you happen to build upon Ti*k*Z `pgfkeys`).

Comment: That's it. Everything works as I wish! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to guess why you want to do this, but you could pass a command without its backslash to `expression` which would enable you to use the command itself after the options are processed.

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.sty}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\DeclareKeys[serdar]
{
   owncommand.code = {\newcommand{\owncmd}{Use this text.}},
   expression.store = \@expression,
   expression.usage = load,
}

\ProcessKeyOptions[serdar]
\newcommand\serdarexpression{\csname \@expression\endcsname}
\endinput
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[owncommand, expression = owncmd]{\jobname}

\begin{document}
Test.
\serdarexpression   
\end{document}
```

[image: output of reconstructed command]

Comment: Thank you, that's a good idea, but it doesn't solve my problem. 
I need for exemple the option `expression = {foo \owncmd}`
I editted my question. You can find the use case and the detailled problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want this, you could use more or less any robust pre-existing command (so it is defined) and locally substitue that command for the saved definition, so
using `\star` here.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[owncommand, expression = something using: \star]{example}

\begin{document}
   Test.

Expression: \makeatletter \@expression\makeatother 

star is still  $\star$
\end{document}
```

You see `\star` still makes `*` except locally in the keyval it is a placeholder for the command specified by the other option. (this place holder could be aby token perhaps `*` would be clearer than `\star`)

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{example}

\DeclareKeys{
   owncommand.code = \def\starreplace{Use this text.}
}

\DeclareKeys{
   expression.store = \@expression,
   expression.usage = load
}

\ProcessKeyOptions

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_replace_all:Nnn\@expression\star\starreplace
\ExplSyntaxOff

\endinput
```

Comment: That's a very good and simple solution. The only disadvantage is the fact that I can't use my own command. So, I'll think about whether I use this solution or whether I just move `\chead{The Prophet \fancysymb}` to the document. Thank you!